# OrderBy method access VBA syntax

Tags: vba, ms-access

Working on a subform, which will filter a record and order by a different field.  The pertinent code:

```
Me.Filter = "[SN] = '" & Me!AcftSN.Value & "'" & " and/
 [Formdate] between #" & Format(Me!startdate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# and/
 #" & Format(Me!enddate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# "

Me.FilterOn = True

 Me.OrderBy = "maf.SysAffected"
 Me.OrderByOn = True

DoCmd.openreport "MAF Summary", acViewReport, , Me.Filter
```

The output report is filtered properly, but not sorted by the sysaffected field.  The output is the same if I delete the orderby lines.

I have also tried

```
Me.OrderBy = "me.SysAffected"
Me.OrderBy = "SysAffected"
Me.OrderBy("maf.SysAffected")
Me.OrderBy,  "maf.SysAffected"
```

and a few other variations, with no effect

Comment: Your question is, why the **report** is not sorted? Or the form?

Comment: I want the report to be sorted, but the orderby command is not affecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you do have a field named *SysAffected*:

```
Me.OrderBy = "[SysAffected] Asc"
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

Comment: Ah, no, of course. It's for the form. To change sorting in the report, you must specify that in the report itself. Search on Grouping and Sorting.